# Meteor: Hold Splash Screen During Wait for Hot Code Push on Mobile Cordova

Tags: cordova, meteor, launch-screen

Would like a Meteor Cordova app to keep the splash screen up while it waits for a hot code push from the server to complete on first run after  downloaded of the app from app store.  This way, the user would be guaranteed to see/get the current (from the server) version of the app with current assets, rather than the version that is on the app store (which might not have all of the current assets, etc).
I have been trying to use these packages:

launch-screen

mdg:reload-on-resume

Based on launch-screen docs, included this in main.js:

```
var lauchScreenHandle = LaunchScreen.hold();
```

Plan was to only include the code:

```
lauchScreenHandle.release();
```

in the version of the code that is deployed to the server, not in the version on the app store, so that code will only display the app UI after the code has refreshed from the server.  Thought this was kind of clever.
However, the .hold() doesn't seem to have much effect. Even with no release(), the app still departs the startup screen and proceeds after the UI renders.  Can't figure out how to prevent this.

Also, the app is a landscape app.  On iOS, while this is happening, the splash screen starts out in landscape, flips to portrait and looks terrible, then the app starts up in landscape based on XCode settings.  The only docs found on this don't seem to resolve it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

LaunchScreen seems to be a client-only op. It won't do anything on the server. To get things working properly, add it to the client-side code of your app.